# How can I use iPhone headsets as a computer microphone?

Tags: audio, microphone, headphones, headset

iPhone headsets have both microphone and headphone functionality using 1 jack. However, my computer has two jacks for two different things: Microphone and headphones. How can I use it for both on my computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to find an adapter that has two plugs for your computer.

Here's one I found by googling, but I can't vouch for the site myself:
http://www.showmecables.com/viewItem.asp?idProduct=8183#

Comment: This works, but I am not sure if that is a economic solution.

Answer (score 4):

The iPhone headset jack is TRRS, so it's a total of 3 channels (1 in, 2 out) with a common ground. This web page has the pinout and some other information: http://geekspeak.org/blog/2008/08/12/iphone-headset-plug
(TRRS = LeftRightGroundMic)

Someone may know of a breakout box or cable, but you're probably going to need to know some electrical engineering to solder a solution for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

It would be much less hassle for you to buy another headset for your computer.  Analogue headsets are extremely cheap on eBay, although I would recommend that you spent a bit more on a USB headset (maybe Plantronics or Logitech) if you are going to use it a lot.

Comment: I'm the downvoter. This really doesn't answer the question. The OP does not want to purchase another headset for some reason, this is quite clear. And I honestly think that the information in this answer, that generic headsets are cheap falls under "obvious common knowledge".