# Realtek doesn't recognize 4pin headset

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, headset

I have a headset with a 4-pin 3.5mm jack that I would like to use on my desktop at work.  The front panel has two 3.5mm jacks. One with just the headset icon and the other with the headset and the microphone icons.

I am suspecting that the one with both is a 4-pin jack. When I plug in the headset, RealTek displays a dialog asking what the device is.  It has the check boxes for line-in, headphones, and microphone.  Despite being check boxes and not radio boxes, I can only check one and I can't use it for both.

How can I force realTek to accept this is a headset or am I wrong in assuming the jack is 4-pin? [The manual](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13412_na/13412_na.PDF) says it is microphone/headphone jack but that doesn't mean it is a 4-pin.  It could just swing both ways.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use iPhone headsets as a computer microphone?](http://superuser.com/questions/175654/how-can-i-use-iphone-headsets-as-a-computer-microphone)

Comment: The desktop manual is implying one of the jacks is a 4-pin connection. If turns out false then this question is void.  Otherwise it is an issue with realtek not recognizing that this is a 4-pin connection, and is different from that question.

Comment: From that manual: "Front Microphone/Headphone jack is **re-task able** to provide Microphone input, line-in ***or*** Headphone
output to support connecting two headphones to the front of the system." -- It does one or the other, not both at the same time -- you'll need a splitter.